# 入り and 付き in these sentences

Tags: words, verbs, syntax, suffixes

I saw some sentences like this, but I couldn't understand them. What do they mean?

> 砂糖入りのお茶。
>
> 胡椒付きのサラダ。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. 砂糖[入り]{いり}のお茶 = 砂糖が入っているお茶
> 2. 胡椒付きのサラダ = 胡椒が付いているサラダ

入り and 付き are suffixes derived from the verbs 入る and 付く. The forms 入り and 付き are the 連用形 *renyōkei* (*masu*-stem) of the verbs and behave much like nouns. This is why you see that 砂糖入り modifies お茶, a noun, with の.

For translation you could go for

> 1. tea containing sugar
> 2. salad with pepper

---

Many verbs do this, by the way. For example the suffix ～生まれ attaches to places and means "born in", e.g.

> 東京生まれの人
> a person born in Tokyo
>
> アメリカ生まれの日本人
> a Japanese born in America

Comment: Could I write 砂糖付きのお茶 and 胡椒入りのサラダ?

Comment: ～付き means "[comes] with", so reading 砂糖付きのお茶 I'd say that it's "tea that comes with a packet/cube/... of sugar". Having it dissolved in the tea, you can't really use ～付き any more. But 胡椒入りのサラダ seems perfectly possible, although ～入り suggests the pepper is really *in* the salad (presumably in the dressing), even though you might not be able to see it.

Comment: @Dav7n Technically, you could, but notice the difference in nuances. ～入り infers something has already been added/mixed in, was ～付き is more like "comes with on the side".  So 砂糖付きのお茶 would sound more like "tea with a side of sugar" as opposed to "sweetened tea".

Comment: @Dav7n I don't think I'd expect to hear much 胡椒入りのサラダ unless we're talking about allergy (, or, you really use pepper as a material, not seasoning).