# How do I ask about books that include furigana for the kanji?

Tags: kanji, questions, furigana

I'm planning on going to Japan soon and one of the things I'd like to do is buy a few books, but I want to get books that include the furigana for all the kanji. How would I ask a store associate to show me where I can find books that include that. My first thoughts go to 「ふりがなの本はありますか？」 but that kind of sounds like "Are there furigana books?" which I'm not sure conveys the correct meaning. Would I be asking that correctly if I said it that way or is there a better way of asking for books that include the furigana?

EDIT: I'm willing to accept a more generalized answer to the question of how to ask about something being included in something else if that makes sense.

Comment: For `a more generalized answer to the question of how to ask about something being included in something else`, this might be of some help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40839/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common way to specify that the printed material must contain furigana would be:

```
ふりがな付きの（本・小説・まんが・etc.）ありますか。
```

or

```
ふりがなの付いている（本・小説・まんが・etc.）ありますか。
```

If you were to use the translation you listed (ふりがなの本）it might confuse the store associate and they would likely ask for clarification.

As they might not have a section dedicated to books with furigana, and they will likely just lead you to the 'books for kids' section, it would probably be best to specify what type of book you are interested in initially.

Comment: ありがとう！ That first phrase was the one I was looking for. 「付き」is the word that was missing from my vocabulary. Is this word typically used as "with"?

Comment: Yes, it is. Something that 'comes with',  'is included', 'is attached' would use this. For example, A book including a DVD would be DVD付 or DVD付き.

Comment: "Books for kids" haha!  :P

Answer (score 4):

For "books with *furigana*" you can use 「ふりがな付きの本」.

Of course books come on a spectrum and all books directed at native speakers of a particular age group contain *kanji* and *furigana* appropriate for this age group. (So, even if you're not native, you can try to read books for natives by reading books below your actual age group.)

For self study, there are also a number of parallel texts, e.g. 講談社バイリンガル・ブックス.